# Managing Own Classes with Composer

Tags: composer-php, autoload, slim

I'm new to composer and autoloaders. I think I also lack of file organization strategies.
I'm trying to build up a new project on slimframework.
I have some classes for Slim. But I can not autoload them in my project.

**/**

- composer.json
- composer.phar
- vendor
- config

  - someapiparams.php
  - database.php
  - cache.php
  - general.php
- public

  - index.php
- models
- libraries

  - Foo
  - Slim

    - Config.php
    - Cache.php

**/composer.json:**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Foo": "libraries/"
    }
}
```

**/libraries/Foo/Slim/Config.php:**

```
<?php
class Config {
    /**
    * Loads a file based on $key param under ROOT . "/config",
    * if not already loaded. 
    * Then returns an array.
    */
    public static function get($key) {}

}
```

**/libraries/Foo/Slim/Cache.php:**

```
<?php
class Cache{
    /**
    * Initialize a caching engine defined in config file if not already done.
    * Then runs corrensponding engine methods for getting and setting.
    */
    public static function init() {
       $config = Config::get("cache");
       // initialize driver.
    }
    public static function __get($key) {}
    public static function __set($key, $value, $params) {}

}
```

**/public/index.php:**

```
require ROOT."/vendor/autoload.php";
$app = new Slim\Slim();
var_dump(Config::get("database")); exit;
//var_dump(Foo\Slim\Config::get("database")); exit;
//var_dump(Slim\Config::get("database")); exit;
```

Error is Config class not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to put:

```
namespace Foo/Slim;
```

at the top of /libraries/Foo/Slim/Cache.php (or have possibly have snipped it for the code example).

If adding the namespace doesn't fix it, you should step through the code with a debugger, and see exactly what files the Composer autoloader is searching for, when it tries to load the class and fails.

Comment: Right. Currently the classname is `\Config`, but the location of the file requires it to be named `\Foo\Slim\Config`. Adding a namespace would help.

Comment: I tried combining so many things in json, directory structure and Classnames etc; I missed namespace declaration. Shame on me. Thank you.

Comment: @WebolizeR What is your suggestion? Pointing at a SplClassLoader class does not explain itself.